# Automated sitecore DB deployments

Tags: jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, sitecore

We are currently using `sitecore 6.x` but are soon upgrading to `8.1`

We have a DEV Server for sitecore SQL. Which contains all Core, Master and Web databases.

Client has similar databases in their environment (obviously). We are trying to automate our deployments, I can do the sitecore codebase using Jenkins, how about Database changes?

I see there are tools like [TDS](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/) and [Unicorn](https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn), which say they can help with automation. But could not get a end-end demo on how those works.

I made a POC using **Unicorn**, that was not very friendly. It might be okay for small sitecore projects.

Can anyone share their experience with TDS or any other alternative for SitecoreDB automation

Comment: There are lots of posts on the subject around see here - https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?ion=1&espv=2#q=sitecore+continuous+integration+TDS If you have a specific question about the process or some more details on why your end to end demos did not work maybe someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on a project right now that is using TDS -> Git -> Jenkins -> Sitecore Powershell -> transformations.

The process is complicated, but it is consistent.

We have four TDS project.

- TDS.Master (layouts, templates, etc..)
- TDS.Master.Framework (Under /Content/Home node container items i.e items that are used as ancillary data for multilists and filtering. NOT real page content. All items are set to "Deploy Once" in TDS)
- TDS.Core
- TDS.Master.Content (this is real content to get dev up and running and testing in QA. Never deployed to prod)

Using Jenkins and SPE we are deploying the TDS.Master, TDS.Master.Framework and TDS.Core. We are also deploying the code, using PowerShell and applying transformations to the config files.

Once a month or as requested, we are destroying the entire QA/Stage environment and rebuilding a completely new Sitecore site with PowerShell. I have modified this solution to rebuild our sites (https://github.com/patrickperrone/Sitecore-PowerShell-Installer).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thank you very much this is very helpful. One question, when you have serialized DB items on your local using TDS, you checking those to GIT, then Jenkin pulls it over,and from Jenkins how does it makes to deploying SQL Server (serialized), do you need to install a copy of TDS on Jenkins server or deploying SQL Server?

Comment: Two ways. One is to run MSBuild on the server and generate the TDS .update package. Two is to run the MSBuild on a different server and push it up to a repo or something like that. Option one is the most common. Run the MSBuild, build the TDS project which outputs a .update package. Then install that package with SPE. On production you would want option #2 if you use CI for production deployments. Here a good link for process #1, http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2016/january/jenkins-and-tds.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One answer I like from [Sitecore community](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/43)

- Git as a source control (TFS for some client - and it really do note
  recommend it.)

  - Branch per environment (CI, QA, UAT, PROD)
  - feature branches
- TDS for serialization, packaging and local deployment
- TeamCity / TFS (may vary per client)
- Deployment to CI on change, QA every night, UAT & PROD per request
- Steps different for each environment

  - e.g. DEV
  - Clean web root + db
  - restore Nuget
  - deploy filed
  - deploy items
  - smart publish
  - run tests in web db container
  - republish
  - reindex
  - merge to QA on success
- Stages may vary depending on amount of
  environments (e.g. working with swapping cores in SOLR, taking off/in
  load-balancer and so on.)
- LESS scripts complication via bundles